# Problems loading images on 3G connections

Tags: css, image, 3g, stellar.js

I've been asked to help diagnose issues with a [website](http://www.signatureannualawards.org.uk) which uses stellar.js to create a parallax type effect that continues to work on mobile devices.

While connected to the office wifi the website loads all images and performs normally. On 4G the website is also fine.

However on 3G the images fail to load on mobile devices (iPad Air 2, Galaxy S6 used to test). The kicker is, the 3G connection at 16Mb/s is four times faster than the very basic office wifi which reaches just 4Mb/s.

The images themselves are seven jpg's which are between 100 and 157 KB in size, most closer to 100 with the total of all seven being 792KB.

My initial suspicion was connection speed or device not being able to handle the images, but after resizing them to be much smaller and finding that they work just fine over the offices much slower wifi connection this sort of rules speed/device power out.

So currently I am at a loss. Any suggestions for how to proceed diagnosing the issue or potential solutions?

Comment: I am using Firefox Developer Edition, using inspect element, the images loaded in css like 192.168.254.127/awards/img/Signature_059.jpg are not loaded. Is the path correct? I am not able to connect to that IP address.

Comment: Another error I obtain is: this page does not redirect correctly

Comment: @silviagreen Oh wow! It's weird that they would load in a new tab the first time I opened the page but then upon refresh would disappear, so I completely neglected to check the location being set in the CSS file.

Thanks for that, saved me a lot of head scratching!

Comment: You are welcome, I will put everything into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images loaded in css have path like 192.168.254.127/awards/img/Signature_059.jpg and they are not loaded. Change with the correct path.